# Oder a one-many list in entity Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity, and i want to order the list of typeValuesList by the field TypeValues -> name (string) in descending order. I want to do this conditionally only when the description is equals to "1" for example. I tried with the @OrderBy annotation but that does not seem to work conditionally, what are my options in this case, can i go with a query?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="DEVICE")
public class Device extends AbstractEntity {

  @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length = 300)
  @Size(max = 150)
  private String description;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID", nullable = false)
  private List<TypeValues> typeValuesList = new ArrayList<>();
}


@Entity
@Table(name="TYPE_VALUES")
public class TypeValues extends AbstractEntity{

  @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
  @Size(max = 25)
  private String name;

}
```

Comment: Missing information: definition of TypeValue class and the jpa repository class that has findAll method

Comment: Added the 2nd entity, the jpa repository class is empty at the moment, i just use findAll method from spring data jpa in the service layer, i perform a check in the service layer if(description == "1") then i want to get the list ordered by name

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do it conditionally the best solution is to sort your collection as needed upon retrieval

in the calling method after retrieving the Device:

```
Collections.sort(device.getTypeValuesList(), Comparator.comparing(TypeValues::getName));
```

Comment: so when do i set the arraylist, after i get the device by findById?, please notice that i have Cascade.ALL on this list, so if this is the case then the performance would take a hit, btw i would not change the cascade because then other issues might come out

Comment: in that case you should simply sort it after retrieving with the service method that calls the retrieving

Comment: that means i have to use java level sorting and not do it with query ?